# How to get the response and request details of channel?

Tags: botframework

I build a chatbot for Facebook messenger by bot framework, and I send Json to facebook, but sometimes the facebook messenger didn't work. So I want to check the real Json the channel sent to Facebook. The application inlight's log didn't have the Json. So I want to know how to get the Json the channel put and get.

Comment: There is not currently a way to do this in bot framework.

Comment: Ok. Maybe is there any way in Azure ?

Comment: currently, there is no solution for this.